# Multi select checkbox doesnt work creating object in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I have a app where people can declare things, within a decla they can say who was present so they have to pay, only its not working. The edit function works but the fileDecla doesn't.
The part that doensn't work is the present people. When i print the people present (via print(request.POST))before i save the decla it gives all the people selected but then it doesnt save them, and when i print(decla.present) i get --> None.(it should be all the people present.

Does someone know a solution to this?

## models.py

```
class Decla(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Lid, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    total = models.FloatField()
    present = models.ManyToManyField(Lid, related_name="present_leden")
    receipt = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="declas/", null=True, blank=True
    )  ## this will need to be put back to nothing when it ends
    verwerkt = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

## views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def fileDecla(request):
    form = DeclaForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(1, request.POST)
        form = DeclaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # print(form)
            decla = form.save(commit=False)
            decla.owner = request.user.lid
            # i tried this line bellow but it didnt work
            # decla.present.set(request.POST["present"])
            decla.save()
            messages.info(request, "Decla was created")
            return redirect("agenda")
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "stand": Stand.objects.get(owner_id=request.user.lid.id).amount,
    }
    return render(request, "finance/decla_form.html", context)


@login_required(login_url="login")
def editDecla(request, pk):
    decla = Decla.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = DeclaForm(instance=decla)
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)

        form = DeclaForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=decla)
        if form.is_valid():
            decla = form.save()
            messages.info(request, "Decla was edited")
            return redirect(request.GET["next"] if "next" in request.GET else "agenda")
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "stand": Stand.objects.get(owner_id=request.user.lid.id).amount,
    }
    return render(request, "finance/decla_form.html", context)
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.widgets import NumberInput, CheckboxSelectMultiple
from .models import Decla


class DeclaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Decla
        fields = "__all__"
        exclude = ["owner", "id"]
        widgets = {
            "present": CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeclaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for name, field in self.fields.items():
            if not name in ["verwerkt", "present"]:
                field.widget.attrs.update({"class": "input"})
            # also tried this
            # elif name == "present":
            #     field.widget.attrs.update({"class": "CheckboxSelectMultiple"})
            else:
                field.widget.attrs.update({"class": "checkbox"})
```

Comment: for clarity it works if i let people select the owner feild, but that is undesirable for this application

Answer (score 0):

Here is something from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

> Another side effect of using commit=False is seen when your model has
> a many-to-many relation with another model. If your model has a
> many-to-many relation and you specify commit=False when you save a
> form, Django cannot immediately save the form data for the
> many-to-many relation. This is because it isn’t possible to save
> many-to-many data for an instance until the instance exists in the
> database.
>
> To work around this problem, every time you save a form using
> commit=False, Django adds a save_m2m() method to your ModelForm
> subclass. After you’ve manually saved the instance produced by the
> form, you can invoke save_m2m() to save the many-to-many form data.

According to this, adding `save_m2m()` after calling `decla.save()` would resolve your issue:

```py
@login_required(login_url="login")
def fileDecla(request):
    form = DeclaForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(1, request.POST)
        form = DeclaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # print(form)
            decla = form.save(commit=False)
            decla.owner = request.user.lid
            # i tried this line bellow but it didnt work
            # decla.present.set(request.POST["present"])
            decla.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            messages.info(request, "Decla was created")
            return redirect("agenda")
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "stand": Stand.objects.get(owner_id=request.user.lid.id).amount,
    }
    return render(request, "finance/decla_form.html", context)
```

However, this seems like a messy solution. See [this antipattern](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/using-commit-false-when-altering-the-instance-in-a-modelform.html) for more info.

My suggestion is to do this:

```py
@login_required(login_url="login")
def fileDecla(request):
    form = DeclaForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(1, request.POST)
        form = DeclaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # This seems like a much cleaner solution and it should resolve your problem
            form.instance.owner = request.user.lid
            decla = form.save()
            messages.info(request, "Decla was created")
            return redirect("agenda")
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "stand": Stand.objects.get(owner_id=request.user.lid.id).amount,
    }
    return render(request, "finance/decla_form.html", context)
```

Disclaimer: the code is untested. Let me know if you have any bugs.